# Errors on kernel.log... how do I fix them?

Tags: kernel

My mac is apparently working fine, no crashes of any kind, but my kernel.log is full of errors and that is worrying me, as I never saw it with messages like that. This is a sample of today, since I booted the machine:

```
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: PMAP: PCID enabled
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.0: Mon Apr  9 19:32:15 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.26.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: vm_page_bootstrap: 3051327 free pages and 78017 wired pages
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: kext submap [0xffffff7f80732000 - 0xffffff8000000000], kernel text [0xffffff8000200000 - 0xffffff8000732000]
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: zone leak detection enabled
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: standard timeslicing quantum is 10000 us
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: mig_table_max_displ = 73
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: TSC Deadline Timer supported and enabled
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=1 LocalApicId=0 Enabled
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=2 LocalApicId=2 Enabled
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=3 LocalApicId=4 Enabled
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=4 LocalApicId=6 Enabled
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=5 LocalApicId=255 Disabled
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=6 LocalApicId=255 Disabled
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=7 LocalApicId=255 Disabled
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=8 LocalApicId=255 Disabled
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: calling mpo_policy_init for TMSafetyNet
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: Security policy loaded: Safety net for Time Machine (TMSafetyNet)
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: calling mpo_policy_init for Sandbox
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: Security policy loaded: Seatbelt sandbox policy (Sandbox)
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: calling mpo_policy_init for Quarantine
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: Security policy loaded: Quarantine policy (Quarantine)
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: Copyright (c) 1982, 1986, 1989, 1991, 1993
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: The Regents of the University of California. All rights reserved.
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: MAC Framework successfully initialized
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: using 16384 buffer headers and 10240 cluster IO buffer headers
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: IOAPIC: Version 0x20 Vectors 64:87
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: ACPI: System State [S0 S3 S4 S5]
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: PFM64 (36 cpu) 0xf10000000, 0xf0000000
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration begin ]
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement: Turbo Ratios 159A
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement: (built 19:39:51 Apr  9 2012) initialization complete
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: console relocated to 0xf10010000
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: PCI configuration changed (bridge=16 device=4 cardbus=0)
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration end, bridges 12 devices 17 ]
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: mbinit: done [96 MB total pool size, (64/32) split]
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: Pthread support ABORTS when sync kernel primitives misused
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib kmod start
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless kmod start
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib load succeeded
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless load succeeded
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient: ready
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: FireWire (OHCI) Lucent ID 5901 built-in now active, GUID c82a14fffe74cc32; max speed s800.
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): 000000009833 0x5ac 0x8403 0x9833
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: ath_get_caps[4038] rx chainmask mismatch actual 7 sc_chainmak 0
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: 1.050824: ath_get_caps[4013] tx chainmask mismatch actual 7 sc_chainmak 0
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: 1.055569: Atheros: mac 448.3 phy 2430.12 radio 0.0
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: 1.055579: Use hw queue 0 for WME_AC_BE traffic
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: 1.055585: Use hw queue 1 for WME_AC_BK traffic
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: 1.055591: Use hw queue 2 for WME_AC_VI traffic
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: 1.055597: Use hw queue 3 for WME_AC_VO traffic
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: 1.055603: Use hw queue 8 for CAB traffic
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: 1.055609: Use hw queue 9 for beacons
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: 1.055673: wlan_vap_create : enter. devhandle=0x39bd0610, opmode=IEEE80211_M_STA, flags=0x1
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: 1.055711: wlan_vap_create : exit. devhandle=0x39bd0610, opmode=IEEE80211_M_STA, flags=0x1.
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: 1.055801: start[1012] sc->sc_inuse_cnt is at offset: 203c, sizeof(_sc->sc_ic) is 25e8
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: [IOBluetoothHCIController::setConfigState] calling registerService
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: rooting via boot-uuid from /chosen: 7653E1EE-09E6-3C68-881A-0C1E4607E108
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: Waiting on <dict ID="0"><key>IOProviderClass</key><string ID="1">IOResources</string><key>IOResourceMatch</key><string ID="2">boot-uuid-media</string></dict>
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: Got boot device = IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/SATA@1F,2/AppleIntelPchSeriesAHCI/PRT0@0/IOAHCIDevice@0/AppleAHCIDiskDriver/IOAHCIBlockStorageDevice/IOBlockStorageDriver/ST31000528AS Media/IOGUIDPartitionScheme/Customer@2
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: BSD root: disk0s2, major 14, minor 2
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: Kernel is LP64
May 20 06:53:00 localhost kernel[0]: USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): 2F9EB01043FF 0x152d 0x2329 0x100
May 20 06:53:03 localhost kernel[0]: BCM5701Enet: Ethernet address 70:cd:60:f3:46:0b
May 20 06:53:04 localhost kernel[0]: Waiting for DSMOS...
May 20 06:53:14 localhost kernel[0]: AirPort_AtherosNewma40: Ethernet address 10:9a:dd:a5:06:47
May 20 06:53:14 localhost kernel[0]: IO80211Controller::dataLinkLayerAttachComplete():  adding AppleEFINVRAM notification
May 20 06:53:14 localhost kernel[0]: IO80211Interface::efiNVRAMPublished():  
May 20 06:53:14 localhost kernel[0]: macx_swapon SUCCESS
May 20 06:53:15 localhost kernel[0]: Previous Shutdown Cause: 0
May 20 06:53:15 localhost kernel[0]: SMC::smcInitHelper ERROR: MMIO regMap == NULL - fall back to old SMC mode
May 20 06:53:16 localhost kernel[0]: kxld[com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily]: The following symbols are unresolved for this kext:
May 20 06:53:16 localhost kernel[0]: kxld[com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily]:  _perf_monitor_register
May 20 06:53:16 localhost kernel[0]: Can't load kext com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily - link failed.
May 20 06:53:16 localhost kernel[0]: Failed to load executable for kext com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily.
May 20 06:53:16 localhost kernel[0]: Kext com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily failed to load (0xdc008016).
May 20 06:53:16 localhost kernel[0]: Failed to load kext com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily (error 0xdc008016).
May 20 06:53:16 localhost kernel[0]: kxld[com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily]: The following symbols are unresolved for this kext:
May 20 06:53:16 localhost kernel[0]: kxld[com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily]:  _perf_monitor_register
May 20 06:53:16 localhost kernel[0]: Can't load kext com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily - link failed.
May 20 06:53:16 localhost kernel[0]: Failed to load executable for kext com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily.
May 20 06:53:16 localhost kernel[0]: Kext com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily failed to load (0xdc008016).
May 20 06:53:16 localhost kernel[0]: Dependency com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily of kext com.apple.driver.AppleIntelMeromProfile failed to load.
May 20 06:53:16 localhost kernel[0]: Kext com.apple.driver.AppleIntelMeromProfile failed to load (0xdc008015).
May 20 06:53:16 localhost kernel[0]: Failed to load kext com.apple.driver.AppleIntelMeromProfile (error 0xdc008015).
May 20 06:53:16 localhost kernel[0]: Kext load request buffer from user space still retained by a kext; probable memory leak.
May 20 06:53:16 localhost kernel[0]: kxld[com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily]: The following symbols are unresolved for this kext:
May 20 06:53:16 localhost kernel[0]: kxld[com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily]:  _perf_monitor_register
May 20 06:53:16 localhost kernel[0]: Can't load kext com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily - link failed.
May 20 06:53:16 localhost kernel[0]: Failed to load executable for kext com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily.
May 20 06:53:16 localhost kernel[0]: Kext com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily failed to load (0xdc008016).
May 20 06:53:16 localhost kernel[0]: Failed to load kext com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily (error 0xdc008016).
May 20 06:53:17 localhost kernel[0]: DSMOS has arrived
May 20 06:53:17 localhost kernel[0]: ** Device in slot: SLOT--1 **
May 20 06:53:17 localhost kernel[0]: kxld[com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily]: The following symbols are unresolved for this kext:
May 20 06:53:17 localhost kernel[0]: kxld[com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily]:  _perf_monitor_register
May 20 06:53:17 localhost kernel[0]: Can't load kext com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily - link failed.
May 20 06:53:17 localhost kernel[0]: Failed to load executable for kext com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily.
May 20 06:53:17 localhost kernel[0]: Kext com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily failed to load (0xdc008016).
May 20 06:53:17 localhost kernel[0]: Dependency com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily of kext com.apple.driver.AppleIntelNehalemProfile failed to load.
May 20 06:53:17 localhost kernel[0]: Kext com.apple.driver.AppleIntelNehalemProfile failed to load (0xdc008015).
May 20 06:53:17 localhost kernel[0]: Failed to load kext com.apple.driver.AppleIntelNehalemProfile (error 0xdc008015).
May 20 06:53:17 localhost kernel[0]: Kext load request buffer from user space still retained by a kext; probable memory leak.
May 20 06:53:18 localhost kernel[0]: kxld[com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily]: The following symbols are unresolved for this kext:
May 20 06:53:18 localhost kernel[0]: kxld[com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily]:  _perf_monitor_register
May 20 06:53:18 localhost kernel[0]: Can't load kext com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily - link failed.
May 20 06:53:18 localhost kernel[0]: Failed to load executable for kext com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily.
May 20 06:53:18 localhost kernel[0]: Kext com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily failed to load (0xdc008016).
May 20 06:53:18 localhost kernel[0]: Dependency com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily of kext com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPenrynProfile failed to load.
May 20 06:53:18 localhost kernel[0]: Kext com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPenrynProfile failed to load (0xdc008015).
May 20 06:53:18 localhost kernel[0]: Failed to load kext com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPenrynProfile (error 0xdc008015).
May 20 06:53:18 localhost kernel[0]: Kext load request buffer from user space still retained by a kext; probable memory leak.
May 20 06:53:23 localhost kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Down on en1. Reason 8 (Disassociated because station leaving).
May 20 06:53:23 localhost kernel[0]: 38.553641: setDISASSOC from ATH_INTERFACE_CLASS disconnectVap
May 20 06:53:23 localhost kernel[0]: 38.553655: switchVap from 1 to 1 
May 20 06:53:26 iMac kernel[0]: [ffffff801b380000][BNBMouseDevice::init][70.12] init is complete
May 20 06:53:26 iMac kernel[0]: [ffffff801b380000][BNBMouseDevice::handleStart][70.12] returning 1
May 20 06:53:26 iMac kernel[0]: [ffffff801c6ac800][AppleMultitouchHIDEventDriver::start] entered
May 20 06:53:26 iMac kernel[0]: [ffffff801c6ab100][AppleMultitouchDevice::start] entered
May 20 06:53:26 iMac kernel[0]: Ethernet [AppleBCM5701Ethernet]: Link up on en0, 1-Gigabit, Full-duplex, Symmetric flow-control, Debug [796d,2301,0de1,0300,cde1,7800]
May 20 06:55:05 imac kernel[0]: AppleBCM5701Ethernet:        0        1 BCM5701Enet::replaceOrCopyPacket worked after N tries
May 20 06:56:31 imac kernel[0]: IOSurface: buffer allocation size is zero
May 20 06:57:01: --- last message repeated 28 times ---
May 20 06:58:00 imac kernel[0]: IOSurface: buffer allocation size is zero
May 20 06:58:30 imac kernel[0]: IOSurface: buffer allocation size is zero
May 20 06:59:14: --- last message repeated 1 time ---
May 20 06:59:14 imac kernel[0]: IOSurface: buffer allocation size is zero
May 20 07:00:56 imac kernel[0]: Limiting closed port RST response from 353 to 250 packets per second
May 20 07:22:36 imac kernel[0]: [ffffff801c6ab100][AppleMultitouchDevice::willTerminate] entered
May 20 07:22:36 imac kernel[0]: [ffffff801c6ab100][AppleMultitouchDevice::stop] entered
May 20 07:22:37 imac kernel[0]: [ffffff8022b41400][BNBMouseDevice::init][70.12] init is complete
May 20 07:22:37 imac kernel[0]: [ffffff8022b41400][BNBMouseDevice::handleStart][70.12] returning 1
May 20 07:22:37 imac kernel[0]: [ffffff803074da00][AppleMultitouchHIDEventDriver::start] entered
May 20 07:22:37 imac kernel[0]: [ffffff80305e7e00][AppleMultitouchDevice::start] entered
May 20 08:03:09 imac kernel[0]: IOSurface: buffer allocation size is zero
May 20 08:03:30 imac kernel[0]: Found client, reallocating 47001600
May 20 08:04:23 imac kernel[0]: IOSurface: buffer allocation size is zero
May 20 08:04:53: --- last message repeated 1 time ---
May 20 08:19:43 imac kernel[0]: Found client, reallocating 94003200
May 20 08:21:39 imac kernel[0]: IOSurface: buffer allocation size is zero
May 20 08:30:30: --- last message repeated 4 times ---
May 20 08:34:54 imac kernel[0]: IOSurface: buffer allocation size is zero
May 20 08:37:32 imac kernel[0]: IOSurface: buffer allocation size is zero
May 20 08:46:53 imac kernel[0]: IOSurface: buffer allocation size is zero
```

as you can see, a lot of stuff failing to load, errors of all sorts... how can I fix them and make these messages go away?

This is Mac OS X Lion, 10.7.4, running on an iMac mid 2011 (iMac 12,2)

thanks.

Comment: I'm no Unix expert, but chances are you can ignore these errors if you're not experiencing any symptoms - log files containing stuff about a failure isn't necessarily an actual problem. The SMC one seems to be discussed here as a "benign" error: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3940135?start=15&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

The errors I can see in that log are to do with kexts (kernel extensions).

Try booting in Safe Mode (described in Apple's [HT1564](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1564)): hold down shift during boot.  The machine will then only load certain kernel extensions.

If this results in less errors in the log, then there might be a problem with the kernel extensions cache (which I believe is bypassed in Safe Mode: see [TS1884](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1884), although this is only marked as relevant to 10.5).

If there does seem to be a problem with the kext cache, then I believe you can safely delete `/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.kext.caches/` and it will be rebuilt, as [this superuser.com question and answer](https://superuser.com/questions/251113/safe-to-delete-system-library-caches-com-apple-kext-caches) explain.  But I would do a little more research in that scenario to check first, since that question is about 10.6.